# SimpleSlide Jquery sideshow mod?

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider

I'm currently attempting to modify a jQuery slideshow plugin.  What I am trying to do is have the middle slide visible first on page load instead of  the first slide in the set of html elements.  I've already managed to have the overflow visible as I plan to have a semi transparent layer cover the two sides of the slider, leaving the middle slide visible.

My modified slider can be found [here](http://grindtalk.com/slider/)

And the modified plugin js file can be found [here](http://grindtalk.com/slider/simpleSlide.js)

CSS/HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
.simpleSlide-container {
    margin: auto 0 auto 0;
    width: 496px;
    height: 300px;
}
.simpleSlide-window {
    margin-left: 48px;
}
.buttons {
    height: 48px;
    width: 496px;
    margin-top: -174px;
    z-index: 9999;

}
.left-button {
    background-image: url(arrows-left.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
    left: 24px;
} 
.left-button:hover { 
    height: 48px; 
    width: 48px; 
    background-position: -48px -0px; 
} 
.right-button {
    background-image: url(arrows-right.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    left: 424px;
    bottom: 48px;
} 
.right-button:hover { 
    height: 48px; 
    width: 48px; 
    background-position: -48px -0px; 
} 
</style>

<body>
<div class="simpleSlide-container">
<div class="simpleSlide-window" rel="group_name">
  <div class="simpleSlide-tray" rel="group_name">

    <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="group_name" style="float: left; display: inline-block; opacity: 1;"> 
    <div><img src="13.jpg" /></div>  
    </div>

    <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="group_name" style="float: left; display: inline-block; opacity: 1;"> 
    <div><img src="30.jpg" /></div>  
    </div>


    <div class="simpleSlide-slide" rel="group_name" style="float: left; display: inline-block; opacity: 1;"> 
    <div><img src="31.jpg" /></div> 
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<div class="left-button" rel="group_name"></div>
<div class="right-button" rel="group_name"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at your JS script at all?

I found the events for the prev,next,jumpto buttons

```
$('.left-button, .right-button, .jump-to').live('click', function() {

        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

        if (!$('div.simpleSlide-tray[rel="' + rel + '"]').is(':animated')) {
            simpleSlideAction(this, rel);
        };
});
```

From the snippet above I would say that its something to do with the below two lines

```
var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

simpleSlideAction(this, rel);
```